# Start cmd /k and then close at the end of another batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, sahi

I've a problem to kill command window launch with cmd /k. To replace in the context, i want to launch automatic tests cases (with SAHI Framework, it ressemble to Selenium for who knows). So, i've to lauch first .bat file which contains tests suites. To test a proxy need to be launched so, i need to launch everything at the same place because we packed all that thing in a Jenkins server.

So for recap I have to create a script with these steps :

1. Set globals variables
2. Launch proxy server (in other terminal)
3. Launch suites of tests cases

Code :

```
rem Start proxy server for handle tests
start cmd /k sahi.bat

rem Starting test suites
testrunner.bat tests.suite http://website.fr/ firefox
```

So, these steps are done and works fine. But i've to close the serveur proxy opened in step-2 after step-3.

**How can i kill the sahi.bat after tests cases ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve what you are looking for. My solution:

```
@ECHO OFF
START "Proxy" sahi.bat
START /WAIT testrunner.bat tests.suite http://website.fr/ firefox && taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq <username>: Proxy"
```

`START "Proxy" sahi.bat` will start a new console with your proxy. The window title will be ***username*: Proxy**. Just try to open a window with START "test" cmd if you are not sure about the window title.

Now `START /WAIT "testrunner.bat tests.suite http://website.fr/ firefox" && taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq <username>: Proxy"` will do two things: it will execute your tests in a new console and kill the proxy server. `&&` means that both commands will be executed one after the other. But this is not enough as your script would start the tests and instantly kill the proxy after that. To avoid this we simply add `/WAIT` to our command to make the script execute the kill command as soon as the test bat terminates.

**TL;DR**

- Start proxy and call the window "username: Proxy"
- Start tests and kill the proxy after the tests are done identifying the right window using the given title "username: Proxy"

Comment: Exactly what i searched for ! Thank you, i've update your code a little bit but it's work perfectly :)